# OSX app not showing the final result in console

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new to Xcode and I am trying to write an "hello world" app in OSX with objective - C. I have faced the problem that my code does not show the result and that it only shows that the program ended with exit code 0.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  h
//
//  Created by abbas on 2016-06-30.
//  Copyright © 2016 abbas. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    //return 0;
}
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFakg.jpg) is the picture of code

Comment: You definitely *need* to return something. This shouldn't work properly. Do you have still the same issue when properly returning 0?

Comment: It just write program ended with exit code 0 it does not show the hello world output

Comment: Yes. This is what you described.

Comment: I spotted the `// return 0;` which should not be commented out. Your program does not properly exit, so I guess this causes the output to not be properly or completely transferred or so

Comment: I have inserted the return 0 in the code and it is not comment any more but Xcode does not show the hello world in console. The console is as the picture shows even when I write return 0 at the end

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that your scheme is setup correctly. You need to specify the right executable, check the "Debug Executable" checkbox, as it tells Xcode to attach the debugger, wich is mandatory for the console output and also ensure that you launch your executable automatically (probably timing out?), otherwise you'd need to launch it manually from the Terminal.

**EDIT**

Also "Clean" and "Clear" your project, as it'll remove probably compromised build scrap.

[image: proper scheme configuration]